# MATLAB - Read multiple *.log files, calculate and save as .*txt in new folder

Tags: matlab, file

I make different measures and save it like *.log files, calculate it and save as .*txt.

```
%Filtering log files 
l = dir('*.log');

%Array size detection
[rows cols] = size(l);

%Choose a last file
file_name =  strcat(strcat(l(rows).folder,'/'),l(rows).name)

%Reading log last file 
fileread = fopen(file_name);

%Convert to float
times = fread(fileread,'float32');

%Filtering times and set to 0 small values
times(times<1e-8)=0;

%Set right times values
times_s = times * 1.0e-06;

%Solve full rotation speed (Hz)
motorspeed_full = 1./(2.*times_s)

%Filtering inf values and set to 0
motorspeed_full(motorspeed_full>1e+10)=0;

%Solve half rotation speed (Hz)
motorspeed_half = 1./(times_s);

A = '.txt';

[filepath,name,ext] = fileparts(file_name);

Xfilename = cat(2,name,A);

dlmwrite(Xfilename,motorspeed_full,'precision','%.3f');
```

So, it's possible to choose a last file, calculating it and convert it to .*txt. So now, I have to make a calculation after every measure.

[image]

**My aim is:**

- Making first 1...n measures (1...n - *.log's and wav's)
- Calculating and saving 1...n *.log's to *.txt's (see picture)
- Create folder with file_name (ex. 20181120_125713) and insert file_name.txt and file_name.wav into this folder structure[image: Aim]

**Questions:**

- How can I converting all *.log files to *.txt files using dlmwrite?
- How can I create a new folder with file_name

  mkdir(name);

for all files?

- How to move the files with same names to folder with same name? Name of folder changes every time, so i can't work with

  movefile source destination

  Thank you very much for any help :*)

Comment: You haven't asked a question!

Comment: Please clarify what your question is or what difficulties you have to reach your "aims" (objectives?)

Comment: Oh, sorry, I change my text below now!

Comment: We are not here to provide code, this is not the purpose if this page. If the question is "what is the code to do this" the answer is: we wont do it for you

Comment: Its not only about code, I need to know a principle to make changes on multiple files!
I can allready: Calculate and save a txt-files. To move file in one new folder. But i want to work with multiple files:
I have 1.log, 2.log, 3.log and 1.wav, 2.wav, 3wav. I need to create 1.txt, 2.txt, 3.txt. Now I want make a folder named "1" and move 1.txt and 1.wav inside. Then make folder named "2" and move 2.txt and 2.wav! And the same with 3..n

Comment: Have you considered using a simple `for` loop for that? if you want to repeat a task multiple time, I would expect to see a loop in the code...

Comment: Hello EBH, yes I think already about for loop, but the filenames are a problem - my filenames are different (not 1,2,3...) (look at the picture please) - the name are expl. '20181110_124518, 20181110_124814, 20181110_124910'. How can I choose a next file in the loop?

Comment: You can obtain all filenames using `dir` command, and then loop over the structure array of the names you get as output. I see know this is what you did in your answer.

Comment: Thank you EBH =)

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution. Maybe it can help somebody:

```
clear all;
clc;

%Filtering log files
l = dir('*.log');
for k = 1:length(l)
    next_name = l(k).name

    %Array size detection
    [rows cols] = size(l);

    %Choose a last file
    file_name = next_name;

    %Reading log last file
    fileread = fopen(file_name);

    %Convert to float
    times = fread(fileread,'float32');

    %Filtering times and set to 0 small values
    times(times<1e-8)=0;

    %Set right times values
    times_s = times * 1.0e-06;

    %Solve full rotation speed (Hz)
    motorspeed_full = 1./(2.*times_s);

    %Filtering inf values and set to 0
    motorspeed_full(motorspeed_full>1e+10)=0;

    %Solve half rotation speed (Hz)
    motorspeed_half = 1./(times_s);

    A = '.txt';

    [filepath,name,ext] = fileparts(file_name);

    Xfilename = [name,A];

    mkdir(name)

    dlmwrite([name,filesep,Xfilename],motorspeed_full,'precision','%.3f');
    % [name,'.wav'],[name, file, name, '.wav']
    movefile([name,'.wav'],[name, filesep, name, '.wav']);
end
```